# Please tell me steps to create two sites under single Tenant(including IIS configuration) sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa

What are the steps to create multiple site under single tenant in Sitecore SXA and required configuration in IIS?

Comment: https://youtu.be/8G7UcNyTHBo Plenty of online documentation and videos.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on Tenant and add Site.
2. Select required features and themes.
3. Open SXA Site Manager from Powershell toolbox and Set Host name in SXA Site manager.
   Refer [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/manage-multiple-sites-with-the-sxa-site-manager.html) for adding new multiple sites with SXA manger.

[image]

[image]

5. Open IIS and create site with same host enter
6. Add host name in host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

Answer (score 0):

SXA has a very standard functionality of creating multitenant sites, Your question involves two steps, one deals with sitecore sxa and one is standard IIS configuration for any standard web based app

1. For creating multiple sites in SXA there are plenty of documentation available but you can start with https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-tenant-and-a-site.html

So first you need to create your tenant by right clicking on your "Content" item and select option tenant like below

[image]

and after that create different sites under them like below

[image]

One your sites are set, you can configure hosts for individual sites so that when you hit that hostname in a browser your site can be resolved using those names, You can find that settings under <> -> Settings -> Site Grouping -> <> and you can find different settings for configuration of site, one of them is a host name and target host name

[image]

2. Second part of it configure IIS, so for that your site should be published and you can create IIS site and point it to the folder of published items, standard app pool settings etc you will need to check, but you can refer to any existing IIS site to know the default settings if you want to manually create a site and point it to the published site folder